# How can I get the latest two dates from a single column, in a single table, for two separate results of a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns 5 columns.

One of the columns shows the latest date value for a row where one column contains either the string "seller-contact" or "buyer-contact".

The original code works fine, and looks like this.

```
SELECT
  TRIM(p.title) AS `Property Address`,
  TRIM(us.name) AS `Staff`,

  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX( n.datecreated)), '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Last Contact Note`,

  DATEDIFF(
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(n.datecreated)), '%Y-%m-%d')
  ) AS `Days Since Last Note`

FROM ias_property AS `p`
LEFT JOIN ias_note_stream AS `ns` ON ns.target_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN ias_note AS `n` ON ns.note_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN ias_user_staff AS `us` ON p.user_staff_id = us.id
WHERE p.status = 'sold' AND p.isarchived = 0
AND us.position = 'SP'
AND (n.data LIKE '%buyer-contact%' OR n.data LIKE '%seller-contact%')
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY MAX(n.datecreated) ASC
```

I tried to achieve the above using two subqueries for each result. It does not fail or result in any error codes. But on the larger, LIVE, database it takes far too long (returning about 270 rows, I'm assuming that with the sub-query's that makes something like 270^270x the time it would take previously; it never finishes it just hangs).

```
SELECT
TRIM(p.title) AS `Property Address`,
TRIM(us.name) AS `Staff`,

(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(n.datecreated)), '%d-%m-%Y') 
    FROM ias_property AS `p`
    LEFT JOIN ias_note_stream AS `ns` ON ns.target_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN ias_note AS `n` ON ns.note_id = n.id
    WHERE n.data LIKE '%buyer-contact%'
    AND p.status = 'sold' AND p.isarchived = 0
    AND us.position = 'SP'
) AS `Last Buyer Contact Note`,

(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(n.datecreated)), '%d-%m-%Y') 
    FROM ias_property AS `p`
    LEFT JOIN ias_note_stream AS `ns` ON ns.target_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN ias_note AS `n` ON ns.note_id = n.id
    WHERE n.data LIKE '%seller-contact%'
    AND p.status = 'sold' AND p.isarchived = 0
    AND us.position = 'SP'
) AS `Last Seller Contact Note`,

DATEDIFF(
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(n.datecreated)), '%Y-%m-%d')
) AS `Days Since Last Note`

FROM ias_property AS `p`
LEFT JOIN ias_note_stream AS `ns` ON ns.target_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN ias_note AS `n` ON ns.note_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN ias_user_staff AS `us` ON p.user_staff_id = us.id
WHERE p.status = 'sold' AND p.isarchived = 0
AND us.position = 'SP'
AND (n.data LIKE '%buyer-contact%' OR n.data LIKE '%seller-contact%')
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY MAX(n.datecreated) ASC
```

Is there some way to make something simpler so I can have something that would look like

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX( 
    n.datecreated WHERE n.data LIKE '%seller-%'
)), '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Last Buyer Contact Note;
```

TLDR: How do I display both results of a WHERE Clause from the same Column as two separate columns (AS `a`, AS `b`) etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `IF` inside the max function to get the max of only certain values.

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(IF(n.data LIKE '%buyer-contact%',n.datecreated,NULL))), '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Last Buyer Contact Note`
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(IF(n.data LIKE '%seller-contact%',n.datecreated,NULL))), '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Last Seller Contact Note`
```

Adding these should not affect the performance of the original query.